# FortiGate 100E update through SquidProxy

Tags: fortigate, fortinet, proxy

I need to update a backend Fortinet FortiGate100E firewall and the only machine in the network whose ip address is authorized for internet access (from the frontend firewall) is 10.1.2.3 running SquidProxy on CentOS linux.

I followed Fortinet's technical note on how to setup the proxy by opening the CLI and issuing

```
config system autoupdate tunneling
set address 10.1.2.3
set port 3128
set status enable
end
```

Now part of the traffic flows through the proxy but there are still connection attempts directly from the firewall to Fortinet servers on port 443. The updates are not working, I opened every port and protocol from the firewall interface to the SquidProxy machine and through tcpdump on the proxy I can see data flowing back and forth like this

```
Internet <---> SquidProxy <---> FortiGate
```

but from the firewall GUI I can see that it's not communicating with the update servers. I haven't been able to redirect ALL traffic from the firewall through the proxy

What other configurations am I missing?

Comment: Just a quick Google search pulled up this document that lists the various ports each product of theirs uses. Have you looked at this?  http://docs.fortinet.com/document/fortigate/6.4.0/ports-and-protocols/303168/fortigate-open-ports

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is to download the current firmware from the support webpage (https://support.fortinet.com) and import it manually over the Admin Web GUI.
That are possible over System->Firmware.

Please be aware of the upgrade path for FortiGates.
https://docs.fortinet.com/upgrade-tool

On that way you don't need any internet connection.